# How to avoid fragmentation warning when moving a column to position 0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.11

single statement of

```
df.insert(0, 'time', df.pop('time'))
```

on large dataframe causing

> warning: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.

is there away to move a column to position ZERO to avoid this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this dataframe:

```
   column1  column2  time
0        1        2     3
1        4        5     6
```

You can reorder the columns and put the `time` column first like this:

```
df = df[["time", *df.columns.difference(["time"])]]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   time  column1  column2
0     3        1        2
1     6        4        5
```

Comment: i'm getting the same warning for when i create new colum in position "0" from  an existing columns  and delete the existing: (dfp.insert(0, 'newColName', dfp.pop('existColName'))), how to fix the warning for this?

Comment: @Hannibal Don't `.insert` and `.pop`, just reorder column names.